# How do I remove GarageBand?

Tags: macos, garageband, ilife

I'm nearly out of space and `~/Library/Application Support/GarageBand` is taking up 1.5 GB and GarageBand.app is taking up 381 MB of my hard disk space.

Can I simply remove the app itself and this folder to remove it from my system?

Comment: It takes up 14.57 GB on my system. I have a lot more GarageBand instruments installed since I also have Apple Logic Studio.

Comment: `/private/var/folders/*/*/C/com.apple.GarageBand/` was about 500 MB on my Mac.

Comment: If you bought it from AppStore, then just LaunchPad, ALT and Click.

Comment: for Sierra, see http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/268848/92712

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yup, if you no longer want it on your system, those are the two biggest offenders in terms of size. To be completely thorough, have a look through ~/Library/Preferences/ for the .plist file and trash that too.

If you're on a purge, it may be worth looking at iMovie/iDVD too if you don't use those.

Comment: I'm presuming that you could re-install these at any time from the iLife DVDs?

Comment: Yes, either an iLife install disc or the second install disc that came with your machine (if it was pre 10.7 that is!). You can edit my question if you like and add that.

Comment: He might also want to delete the loops dir "/Library/Audio/Apple Loops", per [this discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2477994?start=0&tstart=0). Quote: "That will leave GB without loops, but still capable of recording audio." I haven't tested it myself.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can remove `/Applications/GarageBand.app` and `~/Library/Application Support/GarageBand` from your system. In case you are wondering if other files related to GarageBand are remaining, you can get a listing of all files installed by GarageBand by issuing the following command:

```
$ lsbom /Library/Receipts/boms/com.apple.pkg.GarageBand51.bom
```

`lsbom` provides access to the package receipt giving full details of what was installed and where.

Also check for preference .plist files in:

```
$ ls -l ~/Library/Preferences/*garage*
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are like me wanting to move GarageBand elsewhere such as a backup harddrive then

```
$ mkdir -p /Volumes/DEVELOPMENT/BACKUP/Library/Application\ Support/
$ mv ~/Library/Application\ Support/GarageBand/ /Volumes/DEVELOPMENT/BACKUP/Library/Application\ Support/
$ mkdir /Volumes/DEVELOPMENT/BACKUP/Applications/
$ mv /Applications/GarageBand.app /Volumes/DEVELOPMENT/BACKUP/Applications/
```

then if you want to get the Garageband back when you have a larger harddrive, you do the inverse

```
$ mv /Volumes/DEVELOPMENT/BACKUP/Library/Application\ Support/GarageBand/ ~/Library/Application\ Support/ 
$ mv /Volumes/DEVELOPMENT/BACKUP/Applications/GarageBand.app /Applications/
```

You need to run some commands as `sudo` like `$ sudo mv...`.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, no issues, one of the first things I did when I got my Mac.

There may be some plists stored elsewhere, but they will be small in comparison to all the instruments, songs and samples in the Application Support directory.